# Why does if(variable == "a") does not work in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code and it is not working and I can not figure why not, any help will be appreciated a lot.

```
    string datos;
    string estado_ascendente = "a";
    string estado_descendente = "d";
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        datos = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ProcessData));
    }

    private void ProcessData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = datos;
        if (datos.Equals(estado_ascendente))
        {
            textBox3.Text = "Ascendente";
        }
        if (datos.Equals(estado_descendente))
        {
            textBox3.Text = "Descendente";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox3.Text = "error";
        }
    }
```

The program is supossed to write in texBox3 "Ascendente" or "Descendente" but it just writes "error" as if the "if" conditions are not working, also I have tried this alternative and it does not work:

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        datos = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ProcessData));
    }

    private void ProcessData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = datos;
        if (datos == "a")
        {
            textBox3.Text = "Ascendente";
        }
        if (datos == "d")
        {
            textBox3.Text = "Descendente";
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Have you debugged this with the step debugger?... my guess is no. Put a break point on   `textBox1.Text = datos;` step through it, inspect the variables, tell us what you see, what you expect to see, and why you expect that

Comment: No, I want the textbox3 value to change according to the variable "datos", textbox1 is changing accordingly

Comment: So when you put a breakpoint on `if (datos == "a")`, what is in `datos` exactly ? can you paste an example of what visual inspector says

Comment: I think you are right, when i debug it the variable datos appears as:"a\r" which is something that i could no have think of, so the solution is to put inside the "if " the following code:  if (datos == "a\r")

Comment: No the better solution would be to  `TrimEnd(new char[] {' ', '\r', '\n' });` when you get the data

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

If datos=='a' it will check in the first

```
if (datos.Equals(estado_ascendente))
```

which is true and it should put Ascendente in the textbox.
Then it will again check:

```
if (datos.Equals(estado_descendente))
```

which is false, so it will finally end with else and put error in the textbox.

You should have if/else if/else instead of if/if/else, or better yet, use switch.

EDIT: You should also trim your input to get rid of newlines.